# How do traders come up with prices for derivatives?

Tags: pricing

As a follow up to a [recent question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/29855/11645) on why market prices and model prices can sometimes differ substantially, this resulted in a new question.

How do traders come up with prices?

---

Example: Let's say someone wants to buy a swaption. I always assumed it worked like this:

1. Backoffices continuously collect data and recalibrate the pricing models, for example forward rates or option prices (volatilities) are used to calibrate SABR-Parameters.
2. A trader who wants to sell a swaption uses the bank's pricing library to get an estimate for the fair value of the swaption.
3. The trader adds a few basis points to the NPV from step 2 as a fee.

This does not seem to be the standard approach, so what is actually happening?

Comment: Actually that is not a bad description in many cases (highly standard products). But keep in mind that the models require *inputs* some of which may involve human judgement, they can't always be extracted from market data.

Comment: @noob2 my impression is that the example can not be the whole story otherwise market prices would follow model prices much closer. One guess would be: some market participants use more sophisitcated proprietary models?

Comment: @drobertson I am curios to hear your "Parable of the efficient market".

Comment: @noob2 with human judgement do you mean parameters such as grid spacing, interpolation method, etc?

Comment: '@beginner' more than that. for example for CDO models the correlation of defaults was very difficult to estimate, little more than a guess which proved to be way off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two main reasons why market prices are not all perfectly aligned with models:

- each bank uses its own model, its own libraries to calibrate, and its own corrected market prices. You can see this reason as the **secret sauce** of each bank / desk.
- **liquidity costs** are different from one trade and bank to another: (1) do not forget you have different bid and ask prices for the same product (hence for illiquid products the market *prices* are *transaction prices*; they can be different for buys than for sells); (2) when collateralization is needed, the availability and price for collateral can be different from one bank to another; (3) last but not least banks take their inventory into account, if you already sold a lot of risk in one direction, you will now sell it at an higher price (to try to net your inventory back to zero).

To be frank there is a third reason, but I do not like it: some banks / desks may have appetite for risk in given directions. They are ready to take risk. Hence the difference between the "*fair price*" (in your views: i.e. price that models are telling) and the proposed price can be different.
I do not like this third case because banks should be intermediaries (i.e. act as market makers).

Comment: "Motive" is also a factor. My old trader also had the tendency to mark things in such a way that his own PnL volatility is dampened. His quotes basically mean-reverts toward "market" value...